# How to check which (Neo)vim syntax highlighting plugin is being used

Tags: vim, neovim

The title basically explains the gist of it. I am having some issues with my syntax highlighting, and I understand it is possible to check the filetype I am in currently with `:setlocal syntax?` and that I can check the specification of the highlighting with `:syn list`, but I am looking to see what plugin or native Neovim functionality is currently in control of syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the `:syntax` subcommands works with `:help :verbose-cmd`, which is a tool commonly used for debugging mappings, commands, etc. So, without `:verbose` or a dedicated command, you are left with very fuzzy heuristics like:

```
$ vim foo.js
:filter syntax scriptnames
```

which shows what syntax scripts have been sourced in the current session:

```
  6: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syntax.vim
  7: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/synload.vim
  8: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/syncolor.vim
 64: ~/.vim/pack/lang/start/javascript/syntax/javascript.vim
 65: ~/.vim/pack/lang/start/javascript/syntax/javascript/html5.vim
 66: ~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/syntax/javascript.vim
 67: ~/.vim/pack/lang/start/javascript/after/syntax/javascript.vim
```

Comment: When I run that command it returns a long list of files (10+), how can I see which "take precedence" over the other for determining which color text should be?

Comment: None of them. Syntax highlighting is done by two kinds of scripts: *syntax scripts* are in charge of "parsing" your text into "syntax groups" and *colorschemes* are in charge of styling those groups, which become "highlight groups" in that context. If you want to know where the syntax groups are *defined*, then you should follow this answer. If you want to know where the highlight groups are *styled*, do `:verbose highlight` for all the groups or `:verbose highlight GroupName` for a specific group.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I think I phrased my question poorly given the distinction between those two script types. When there are multiple syntax scripts active at the same time, what determines/how can I determine the precedence for the syntax group a piece of text is assigned when there are conflicting results from the syntax script? (when I said "which color text should be" I think I should have said _what syntax group text should be_)